# Constructing vector<int> with large size

Tags: c++, macos, memory-management, vector

I'm runnig the following code  on OS X 10.9.3, 2.4 GHz Intel Core i5, 8 GB DDR3

## a.cpp

```
int main() {
  vector<int> expectation(10e8, -1.0);
  cout << "size()=" << expectation.size() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

## b.cpp

```
int main() {
  vector<int> expectation(10e9, -1.0);
  cout << "size()=" << expectation.size() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

-

```
$ time ./a.out 
size()=1000000000

real    0m3.935s
user    0m1.530s
sys 0m2.103s

$ time ./b.out 
size()=10000000000

real    4m49.853s
user    0m16.186s
sys     0m22.966s
```

In b.pp we have 10 times larger vector.
I wonder, why the time in case **b** case became in about 100 times bigger than case **a**?

**UPD**
I have found, where I was lost!
*10e8 = 10^9* ints = 4 GB
*10e9 = 10^10* ints = 40 GB

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming 4 bytes per `int`, the first uses 4GB of memory and fits comfortably into you 8GB of RAM. The second uses 40GB, and needs to keep swapping to disk. That will be much slower.

Note that `10e9` means 10x10<sup>9</sup>, or 10<sup>10</sup>. It's possible you thought it meant 10<sup>9</sup>, which would fit in RAM. That would be `1e9`.

Comment: no. For 10^8 int's we need 400MB and for 10^9 - 4GB

Comment: @Enor: See the last sentence. Your tests are for 10^9 and 10^10 ints.